# CLOSED White space between header and image background React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a little problem in my react-native mobile app.

There is a Space between the header and the  Background Image.
How can I remove it, like the Background Image is next to the Header ?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHDBO.jpg)

App.js

```
import AppNavigator from './navigation/AppNavigator';

import Header from './components/Header';

export default function App(props) {
  const [isLoadingComplete, setLoadingComplete] = useState(false);

  if (!isLoadingComplete && !props.skipLoadingScreen) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={loadResourcesAsync}
        onError={handleLoadingError}
        onFinish={() => handleFinishLoading(setLoadingComplete)}
      />
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <Header title="Header" />
        {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <StatusBar backgroundColor="#C2185B" barStyle="default" />}
        <AppNavigator />

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Header.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const Header = props => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.header}>
                <Text style={styles.headerTitle}>MyStadium</Text>
        </View>
    )
};


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    header: {
        width: '100%',
        height:90,
        backgroundColor: 'black',
        paddingTop: 36,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent:'center',
    },
    headerTitle: {
        color:'white',
        fontSize: 18
    }
});

export default Header;
```

And The AppNavigator is the base file in the tabs pre-config react-native project.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Give the image styling of `flex:1` or try giving it width and height

Answer (score 1):

remove `paddingTop: 36` from container styles
like below

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    header: {
        width: '100%',
        height: 90,
        backgroundColor: 'black',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent:'center',
    },
    headerTitle: {
        color:'white',
        fontSize: 18
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got this !

Just have to remove my Header.js and use de navigationOptions like this

```
HomeScreen.navigationOptions = {
  title: 'MyStadium',
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: 'black'
  },
  headerTintColor: 'white',
  headerTitleStyle: {
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  }
};
```